# Are there any built-in WinJS ListView item templates for Windows Phone?

Tags: listview, user-interface, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I want to build a simple list view on my Windows Phone 8.1 app written on HTML + JavaScript, but I'm having trouble finding a built-in template for a regular list item with just a single line of text.

On Android you have built-in layouts, is there an equivalent on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing built in, but MSDN does contain some item template references:

- [Item templates for list layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465478.aspx)
- [Item templates for grid layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465463.aspx)

These are subtopics from the one that Rob referred to and give you both HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

No, there aren't any predefined templates built in.

See [Quickstart: Adding a ListView (HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465496.aspx#defining_item_templates) for a walkthrough to create your own.